# Saving Text file results to LinQ to sql table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, filereader

I've made some code to read a file line by line using some sort of a linq way. Now  I need some suggestions on how to insert each line separated by comma in the database object. I've made this on another code but it was using a while loop which is this case seems to be kind of hard for a beginner in linq. fileReader is the name of the table that works like declaring an obj for a class.  DataClasses1DataContext is the class for the connection created by linq. as for now I can insert values 0,1 and 2 into the sql table but no more than that. Any help or suggestions will be highly appreciated. :) Thank you!

```
    DataClasses1DataContext db; 

    private void Readbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> List = new List<string>();

        FileReader fr = new FileReader();

        var read = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Files\Archivo.txt").SelectMany(line =>     line.Split(',')).ToArray();

        foreach (var word in read )
        {

            List.Add(word);
            listBox1.Items.Add(word);

        }


            fr.Matricula = List[0];
            fr.Nombre = List[1];
            fr.Sueldo = decimal.Parse(List[2]);


            db.FileReaders.InsertOnSubmit(fr);
            db.SubmitChanges();


    }

    private void Show_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        db = new DataClasses1DataContext();

        dataGridView1.DataSource = db.FileReaders.ToList();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    }
```

Comment: firstly, you can use List.AddRange(read), listBox1.Items.AddRange(read) instead of going thru loop

Comment: WHat is your archivo.txt structure? Am i getting right that every 3 values in "read" should produce one object?

Comment: my interest is not actually the listbox is actually the fr.matricula which is my obj for the sql table

Comment: Archivo struct is *******,asasaassa,7465656
56455645646,sdfsfsf,564645654
546346,dfgg,30000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope i'm getting you right. Looks like every line in your file contains 3 values for Matricula, Nombre and Sueldo. If so, then you try to go another way:

```
var readers = new List<FileReader>();    
System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Files\Archivo.txt").ToList()
.ForEach(l => { 
    string[] splitted = l.Split(','); 
    readers.Add(new FileReader(){ 
        Matricula = splitted[0], 
        Nombre = splitted[1], 
        Sueldo = decimal.Parse(splitted[2])
    }); 
});
```

Thus you have array of FileReader values. Then:

```
List.AddRange(readers.Select(r => r.Matricula));  
listBox1.Items.AddRange(readers.Select(r => r.Matricula));  
db.FileReaders.InsertAllOnSubmit(readers);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Hello JIm, thank you for your response, can you explain what have you done here? I did the same thing, but I had to convert l[0].Tostring() and when I try to add the file it just comes with an error that is an incorrect format. Can you please explain or verify? ty

Comment: Input string was not in a correct format. and it happens on the first value Matricula.

Comment: Give me FileReader class declaration and the first true line of your file.

Comment: and this : listBox1.Items.AddRange(readers.Select(r => r.Matricula));  it says that has some invalid arguments

Comment: 20080220,Alexander,25000. FileReader is my SQL Table , I just did this in my other code: FileReader fr = new FileReader(); and DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();

Comment: @AlexDev4Life i dont have an idea what types your Matricula and other of. I can't guess.

Comment: Ok Sorry, didnt get that. Matricula is declared on the table as varchar(50), nombre as well, and Sueldo is as decimal(18,0). let me know if that helps

Comment: What are the types of Matricula, Nombre and Sueldo in the aplication?

Comment: Those 3 comes directly from my LinQ table , FileReader.Matricula...etc . I Understand that that l is an object of FileReader and for instinct it will give me all the fields from the table. Or maybe im confused.

Comment: Does this "var readers = ..." produces "input string was not in correct fprmat"?

Comment: Yes, Im trying something else now to test, The error is produced when the code gets to the Matricula part.

Comment: this is what Im trying. this is so weird. var readers = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Files\Archivo.txt").SelectMany(line => line.Split(',')).Select(x => new FileReader() { Matricula = x[0].ToString(), Nombre = x[1].ToString(), Sueldo = x[3].ToString() }).ToList();

          /*  prop.matricula = readers[0].ToString();
            prop.nombre = readers[1].ToString();
            prop.sueldo = (readers[2]).ToString();*/
            
            db.FileReaders.InsertAllOnSubmit(readers);
            db.SubmitChanges();

Comment: @AlexDev4Life it's impossible as source value is string and Matricula is string as well. Probably the error occurs wneh assigning Sueldo. If you file has incorrect decimal values then that would be an error. Try using Sueldo = decimal.Parse(l[2], new CultureInfo("en-US")) instead of Sueldo = decimal.Parse(l[2]) or set the other culture that has same decimal separators as in your file.

Comment: see, when I remove the [index] from x it print on each line of the table the same result, I mean for matricula, nombre, sueldo is printing the same value . for example the 20080220 is printing it in the 3 different columns , then the name is printing it on the next line 3 times.

Comment: Ive changed already the value from decimal to varchar and string as well so it shouldnt be a problem now

Comment: @AlexDev4Life ah i see, i was wrong (didnt run code). Try this instead:             var readers = new List<FileReader>();
            System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Files\Archivo.txt").ToList().ForEach(l =>
                {
                    string[] splitted = l.Split(',');
                    readers.Add(new FileReader(){ Matricula = splitted[0], Nombre = splitted[1], Sueldo = decimal.Parse(splitted[2])});
                }
                );

Comment: My man, that's it, lol I already have a headache! hehehe, it was worth it at least, Thank you. PS: Try always to run the code to help better lol

Comment: @AlexDev4Life updated my brilliant answer. It's just left to upvote and accept it ;)